# Генерация POJO из XSD 1.1 при сборке проекта

Tags: java, maven, xsd

Я пытаюсь настроить генерацию Java классов при сборке проекта с использованием плагинов Maven. В частности, использовал manen-jaxb2-plugin и cxf-xjc-plugin. Но в итоге получаю ошибку:

```
The content of 'requiredDataType' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: alternative.
```

Как я понимаю, xjc не поддерживает XSD 1.1, но есть ли возможность для настройки генерации при сборке проекта?

Пример:

```
    <xs:complexType name="TRequestEGRNAccessAct">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Запрос на предоставление доступа к ФГИС ЕГРН</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="requiredDataType" type="tns:TRequiredData">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Запрашиваемые данные</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:alternative test="@dataType = 'requiredDataSubject'"
                    type="tns:TRequiredSubjectData"/>
                <xs:alternative
                    test="empty(index-of((&quot;requiredDataRealty&quot;, &quot;requiredArea&quot;, &quot;requiredBorder&quot;, &quot;requiredRealtyList&quot;), @dataType))"
                    type="tns:TRequiredData"/>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример xsd с которым возникают ппоблемы

Comment: Вся проблема в аннотациях "alternative", если убрать их убрать, генерация завершается успешно...